# DetailsView image updating problem

Tags: asp.net, image, file-upload, detailsview, findcontrol

I have DetailsView with users Info (Name, Email, Picture). That DetailsView control can be edited. 
Values are from DataBase

```
 protected void DVUserInfoShow_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{


    FileUpload EditAvatar = (FileUpload)DVUserInfoShow.FindControl("EditAvatar");
    if (EditAvatar.HasFile)
    {
        string image_path = "~/images/user_images/" + EditAvatar.FileName;
        EditAvatar.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(image_path));
        e.NewValues["Avatar"] = EditAvatar.FileName;

    }

    else
    {
        e.NewValues["Avatar"] = e.OldValues["Avatar"];
    }



}
```

The problem is with **e.NewValues["Avatar"] = e.OldValues["Avatar"];**, when user updates his name and email, the picture value is set to null. And that code doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OldValues` collection is only available when `DetailView` is bounded with a declarative `DataSource`, otherwise `OldValues` collection will contain `null` in `ItemUpadting` event.

What you can do is inside `DVUserInfoShow_ItemUpdating` event, get current data from database and save in some local variables.

Comment: Now i know the answer, i used declarative DataSource, but it didn't work anyway.. The problem was that i didn't set DataKeyNames..